# "Code component" meaning, please

Tags: meaning

Context of problematic understatding

```
Find code components and tools for <task1>, <task2>...
```

All tasks and targets are IT-related, **not coding** (where "code components" are usable and understandable term) per se.

For me "code components" != "key components" (and I know|understand the latter form)

Extended context

> ... services easily integrate with 3-rd party tools for:
>
> - deploy apps
> - Find code components and tools for /different development-related activities  here/
> - /another advantages/

Comment: No idea. This isn't a question of English, but either IT jargon or a misuse of it. Can you give us more context? What text appeared around this sentence? Where did you find it?

Comment: @DanBron - IT-company offer solutions for (almost) full ALM ("application lifecycle management"), this is part of possibilities. And _for me_ (not native English-speaking) it's a question of *English*, while I'm in the same business

Comment: If, as you claim, it's not related to coding, you're probably better off asking the author. There are a couple of non-standard terms in the extended context: "3-rd" and "agvantages". They might be using *code components* in a non-standard way as well.

Comment: stop down voting lawrence, you are not that great

Answer (score -1):

Code components are libraries. Users can extend the class of the code component or implement it to use the methods in the code component

Comment: But OP said this is **not related to coding**.

Comment: oh, then it could mean a classifying property. red haired, blonde, brunette etc,

Comment: Sure *code* here is a noun adjunct, i.e. a noun acting like an adjective, aka a classifying property. By the OP's specific question is: what does it *mean*? What specific properties is is classifying?

Comment: the OP should have mentioned tasks and the things from which he has to find the code comps n tools

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked for those things in a comment under his question rather than answering ;) . It's not really helpful to answer unclear questions.

Comment: ha, but i can't comment till i get to 50 points, maybe if you goto some of my answers and up vote them then next time i will comment ;)

Comment: Haha, the rule isn't "answer because you can't comment", it's "answer *when you have an actual answer*, and forebear from answering when you don't, until you've earned enough rep to put mom-answer thoughts in comments" ;)